# Modal com Contagem regressiva

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, modal

Criei um modal com o Bootstrap, e criei em um arquivo separado um cronometro em Javascript. 
Porem eu queria que esse cronometro rodasse dentro do Modal.
Como faço para proceder? 
Desde já obrigado!

Código do Modal:

```
<div class="bs-example">
    
    <div id="QuestaoModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" width="200px">
                  
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Código da Contagem Regressiva:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var segundo = new Number();
            var segundo = 180;

            function start() {
                if ((segundo - 1) >= 0) {
                    tempo.innerText = count;
                    count = count - 1;
                    setTimeout('start();', 1000);
                }
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="start();">
        div id ="tempo"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Você pode usar a função [setInterval()][1] e mudar o texto selecionando o id ou classe de onde você quer que apareça o tempo.

Outras perguntas relacionadas:

  [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer
  [3]: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128608/como-fazer-timer-em-javascript

Comment: O usuário que fez essa pergunta não entra desde 2016... provavelmente não vai aceitar a resposta...

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que eu entendi, voce quer iniciar uma contagem assim que a modal e aberta.
Voce pode fazer isso utilizando os callbacks `shown.bs.modal` e `hidden.bs.modal` da modal do bootstrap, disparando o timer no momento em que ela e exibida, e limpando ele quando a modal e fechada.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f32toygj/): https://jsfiddle.net/f32toygj/

```
function timer(elToUpdate) {

    var maxTime = 60;

    elToUpdate.text(maxTime);

    var interval = setInterval(function () {

        if (maxTime > 0) {
            maxTime--;
            elToUpdate.text(maxTime);
        }
        else {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

    }, 1000);

    return interval;
}

         $("#QuestaoModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {

            var t = timer($('#modal-time'));

            $(this).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                clearInterval(t);
                $('#modal-time').text("");
                $(this).off('hidden.bs.modal');
            });
        });
```