# É possível colocar um timer antes de executar um post/reload na página?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a function abaixo que ao final da operação da um reload na página afim de atualizar os status.

Seria possível colocar um tempo de esperar para executar esse reload ?

```
  function ConsultarChangeDll(numero) {
        var status = $("#sclStatusGrid_" + numero).val();
        if (status == "L") {
            swal({
                title: "",
                text: "Confirmar operação?",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
                confirmButtonText: "Sim",
                cancelButtonText: "Não",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: false
            },
                function (isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                        ControleEstoqueFranquia(numero);
                        swal("", "Operação realizada.", "success");
                        window.location.reload();
                    } else {
                        swal("", "Operação cancelada.", "error");
                        window.location.reload();
                        return;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `setTimeout`

```
// a pagina será atualizada em 5 segundos.
window.setTimeout(window.location.reload, 5000);
```

por um outro lado, este `SweetAlert` retorna uma `Promise`, então você pode esperar que o usuário feche o dialogo.

```
var timeout = window.setTimeout(window.location.reload, 5000);
swal("", "Operação realizada.", "success").then(function () {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout)
    window.location.reload()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a [função global `setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp), ela serve para criar um *delay* simples antes da execução única de alguma função passada nos parâmetros.

```js
setTimeout(teste, 2000); // vai executar a função 'teste' depois de 2000 milisegundos (ou 2 segundos)
function teste() {
     console.log("Executou depois de 2 segundos");
}
```

Existe também a [função setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). Esse método executa uma função em *intervalos* de tempo, isso significa que será executada diversas vezes até que você a mande parar:

```js
var contador = 0;
var intervalo = setInterval(teste, 2000); // vai executar a função 'teste' de 2 em 2 segundos.
function teste() {
    console.log("Executou depois de 2 segundos");
    contador++;
    if(contador > 10) {
        console.log("Cancelou a execução");
        clearInterval(intervalo); // cancela a execução do 'intervalo'
    }
}
```

No seu código você pode fazer:

```
function ConsultarChangeDll(numero) {
    var status = $("#sclStatusGrid_" + numero).val();
    if (status == "L") {
        swal({
            title: "",
            text: "Confirmar operação?",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
            confirmButtonText: "Sim",
            cancelButtonText: "Não",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false
        },
            function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    ControleEstoqueFranquia(numero);
                    swal("", "Operação realizada.", "success");
                    setTimeout(recarregarPagina, tempo); // substitua 'tempo' pelo tempo em milisegundos
                } else {
                    swal("", "Operação cancelada.", "error");
                    setTimeout(recarregarPagina, tempo); // substitua 'tempo' pelo tempo em milisegundos
                    return;
                }
            });
```

Então, você coloca o `reload` dentro da função:

```
function recarregarPagina() {
     window.location.reload();
}
```

Outra opção seria você criar um objeto Timer. [Essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128608/como-fazer-timer-em-javascript) do Sergio explica detalhadamente como criar esse objeto.